# CodeIgniter Form Validation Error Redirect

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have the following controller, which works fine in terms of validating the form and displaying the error.

The user attempts to login from: http://mydomain.com/index.php/login

However, when the user enters the wrong credentials, it loads the login view properly (as it should) and displays the error "Invalid Login" properly, but the URI in the browser window shows:

http://mydomain.com/index.php/verify_login (as opposed to the one above).

How do I redirect after the failed validation to just ".../index.php/login"

Here is the code in question:

```
<?
   class Login extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form'));
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('login_page');
}

function verify_login() 
{

$this->load->model('login_model','',TRUE);
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<label class="error">', '</label>');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Login', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
 //Field validation failed. User redirected to login page
 $this->index();
}
else
{
 //Go to private area
 redirect('private_area', 'refresh');
 }

}

function check_database($password)
 {
  //Field validation succeeded. Validate against database
  $username = $this->input->post('username');

  //query the database
  $result = $this->login_model->login($username, $password);

  if($result)
   {
   $sess_array = array();
   foreach($result as $row)
   {
     $sess_array = array(
     'id' => $row->id,
     'username' => $row->username
   );
   $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
 }
 return TRUE;
}
 else
 {
 $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', '<div class="alert alert-error">Invalid username or password</div>');
 return false;
 }
 }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Cyrode's solution fixes that issue, but now it's not displaying the "Invalid Login" error message (set_message) from the check_database() function on loading the view. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

**UPDATE 2:** 
Here you go:

```
  class Login extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form'));
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('login_page');

    $this->load->model('login_model','',TRUE);
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<label class="error">', '</label>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Login', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

 if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
   $this->load->view('login_page');
  }
 else
 {
 //Go to private area
 redirect('private_area', 'refresh');
 }
}

 function check_database($password)
  {
   //Field validation succeeded. Validate against database
   $username = $this->input->post('username');

    //query the database
    $result = $this->login_model->login($username, $password);

   if($result)
   {
    $sess_array = array();
     foreach($result as $row)
    {
     $sess_array = array(
     'id' => $row->id,
     'username' => $row->username
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
  }
  return TRUE;
 }
else
{
  $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', '<div class="alert alert-error">Invalid username or password</div>');
 return false;
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do all of your form processing in the `index()` method.

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('login_model','',TRUE);
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<label class="error">', '</label>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Login', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
    {
        $this->load->view('login_page');
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('private_area', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Then, make sure your form's action goes to `login` and not `verify_login`.

By the way, don't xss_clean password fields, because it may change their value, and your user will be left wondering why their perfectly-typed password isn't working. You should be hashing the password, anyway, which will eliminate security issues.

Comment: Hey Cryode, thanks, this fixes that issue, but now it's not displaying the "Invalid Login" error message from the check_database() function on loading the view.  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know why that functionality would've stopped -- all this does is consolidate the same code into one method instead of using two. Maybe add your current code to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment on the xss and hashing.  Will do that.

Comment: Looks like you have your view load twice now. You only need the one inside the form validation check. See if that fixes the issue.